# Video size cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently building a phonegap project with the Ionic framework, i need to capture video, here is my code

```
$scope.captureVideo = function(){
      var options = { duration: 15 };
      $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
        $scope.videoGo = videoData[0].fullPath;
        $scope.debug = videoData;
      }, function(err) {

      });
    };
```

the video size is way to big even for a 15 second video, is there anyway to control the resolution of the video? it's being recorded in full HD 1080p, this will become a problem for 3g users and with a data limitation plan. or at leat to take down the quality for less weight.

Comment: Did you try the CaptureVideoOptions? There is a width and a height option you can set

Comment: The only options are Properties

limit: The maximum number of video clips the device's user can capture in a single capture operation. The value must be greater than or equal to 1 (defaults to 1).

duration: The maximum duration of a video clip, in seconds.